# Finding the friction before slipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, torque, moment

There is a string that is attached to a bar as shown below in the picture. What is the coefficient friction between the bar and floor before bar starts slipping.

[image]

I have chosen a pivot point about the point where the bar contacts with the ground.

The equation for the torque about the point where bar contacts with the ground ->

$$ - mg *1.4863 - T*1.814989 = 0 $$

I found 1.814989 by using the cross product.

Then
$$
F_x = 0\\
-T\sin 21 - F_{friction} = 0\\
-T\sin 21 - \mu N = 0\\
F_y = 0\\
-mg + N + T\cos21 = 0\\
$$
Now, i'm stuck and i don't how to proceed further. Also, i'm confused about this part -> 
Is the formula for friction $f = \mu N$, is N equal to mg ?

Comment: Please use Mathjax.Visit : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**:
[image]

**Torque** on the rod about point on the ground, Since the rod is not rotating the $\tau_{net}=0$ 
$$
Tl\cos69-mg\frac l2\cos42=0\\
$$
**Forces** acting on the rod, Since the rod is not slipping $F_{net}=0$
$$
N=mg-T\sin69\\
T\cos69-F_{friction}=0\\
F_{friction}=\mu N\\
$$
$$
F_{friction}=\mu(mg-T\sin69)\\
T\cos69-\mu(mg-T\sin69)=0
$$
There you go now I think you can finish off the problem.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused how did you get the equation for the torque. Should not the mg*cos42 will be also multiplied by the distance to the pivot point?

Comment: thank you ! i was on the right track and just did not see that i could substitute N to the first formula ! Still confused about your Torque formula, but thank you !

Comment: @student123 Yeah, Sorry about that, my mistake! I have made the edits!